# Redirect user to the content of my page

Tags: php, facebook

I am using facebook account for the user to login into my website. I successfully did it but, after the user has successfully logged in with facebook account it is still stuck to the login page.

MY code:

```
    <script>

    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1421518261398144";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
     // app, and response.authResponse supplies
     // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
     // request, and the time the access token 
     // and signed request each expir    window.location = "";e

    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
      window.location = "http://record.comxa.com/server/home.php";
    } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
    }
   });

   </script>
```

Comment: Not familiar with the FB API, but it seems like you would need to put a `window.location` in the first `if` block after `uid` and `accessToken`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code (replace `URL` with your success page `URL`) :

```
window.location = "URL";
```

Below this code:

```
  var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
```

With that in place, It should redirect the user up on login in successfully, to the success page.

Comment: He's already doing that. The problem here, I guess, is that he's doing it in a wrong place.

Comment: or maybe he need it in both places, since it`s separate checks?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the part of the code, where you're redirecting the user, to the first *if* block. It should look like this:

```
<script>

        (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1421518261398144";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        window.location = "http://record.comxa.com/server/home.php";
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
        // but has not authenticated your app
        } else {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }
       });

</script>
```